# Passing array problem in retrofit post request

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

I have face a problem retrofit library in android java.

here is the json Body

```
{
"title":"Android ",
"type":"project",
"category_id":"1",
"tags":["swift","java","android"],
"end_date":"2021-9-30",
"description":"testing",
"budget":"500"
```

}

This the pojo class

```
public class draftedJobPostModel {
private String title;
private String type;
private int category_id;
ArrayList<String> tags;
private String end_date;
private String description;
private int budget;
private String post_type;

public draftedJobPostModel() {
}

public draftedJobPostModel(String title, String type, int category_id, ArrayList<String> tags, String end_date, String description, int budget, String post_type) {
    this.title = title;
    this.type = type;
    this.category_id = category_id;
    this.tags = tags;
    this.end_date = end_date;
    this.description = description;
    this.budget = budget;
    this.post_type = post_type;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public int getCategory_id() {
    return category_id;
}

public void setCategory_id(int category_id) {
    this.category_id = category_id;
}

public ArrayList<String> getTags() {
    return tags;
}

public void setTags(ArrayList<String> tags) {
    this.tags = tags;
}

public String getEnd_date() {
    return end_date;
}

public void setEnd_date(String end_date) {
    this.end_date = end_date;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public int getBudget() {
    return budget;
}

public void setBudget(int budget) {
    this.budget = budget;
}

public String getPost_type() {
    return post_type;
}

public void setPost_type(String post_type) {
    this.post_type = post_type;
}
```

}

Add value from chip:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayTags = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i=0;i<chipGroup.getChildCount();i++)
        {
            Chip chip = (Chip) chipGroup.getChildAt(i);
            arrayTags.add(chip.getText().toString());
        }
```

retrofit call method:

```
Service service = Client.retrofit.create(Service.class);
        Call<createJobPostModel> call = service.createJob("Bearer"+" "+token,title,jobtype,fieldId, arrayTags,date,budget,description);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<createJobPostModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<createJobPostModel> call, Response<createJobPostModel> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()){
       /*             Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),arrayTags.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    /*arrayTags.clear();*/
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<createJobPostModel> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Everything is ok but when i pass the arraylist its shows only last index of array value in database.

here is the return value:

```
   "tags": "Android",
```

but i want this:

```
"tags": [
            "swift",
            "IOS",
            "android"
        ],
```

Comment: By the way, your category ID and budget are strings in your shown JSON, not integers like your POJO is written

Comment: In any case, you're never using `response`, so it's unclear what you expect to happen. Can you show what the raw server response is for the input given? Also, some out of context arraylist and "chips" code is not useful. Please show a [mcve] of the full activity/fragment